# Apex Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Hi i'm new to sql and still trying to learn, can someone point to me where my mistake is
so this is the same code written twice once with an alias referring to the element (select *.....)
and the other one is without it. The first code is working fine while the other gives me "missing an expression" error, i know it's not ideal to write it that way but i dont see where the missing expression is ?

The first code

```
select *
from (select * from dept) d  left outer join (select * from emp where job = 'SALESMAN') e
on e.deptno=d.deptno
```

the second code

```
select *
from (select * from dept)  left outer join (select * from emp where job = 'SALESMAN') 
on (select * from emp where job = 'SALESMAN').deptno=(select * from dept).deptno
```

Answer (score 2):

> where my mistake is so this is the same code written twice once with an alias referring to the element (select *.....) and the other one is without it.

Exactly that's your mistake. You can't use the whole subquery as an ... alias (?) (don't know how to name *construct* you made).

---

Though, we usually write it way simpler as

```
select *
from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
                           and e.job = 'SALESMAN';
```

Comment: i wasn't trying to use it as an alias i was simply trying to refer to it just for the sake of understanding how sql works but anyways i can give the subquery an alias and i did it on the first code and everything worked fine and in case you wonder why am i even using a subquery here where i should not it's simply for the purpose of learning in case i wanted to add some conditions like (where,and) to the query of each table at a time.

Comment: but wait in your code you gave an alias to the table and then started right away with and<condition> right away without using where is it okay to do that and also i see you did put the condition job='SALESMAN' outside the from element while still refering it where you want it to be which is the alias of dept d is that fine too ?

Comment: OK, no problem in trying what SQL can, feel free to combine it in any possible way. Doing so, you'll learn a lot - what you can, what you can not, what you can but doesn't produce correct result and so on. As of your 2nd comment: what you call a "condition" (`and e.job = 'SALESMAN'`) is **not** a condition; conditions are to be put into the WHERE clause. In my example, this is part of the *join*; I just put it into a new line to improve readability.

Comment: hmmmm so sql doesn't allow me to refer the whole subquery and therfore i have to give it an alias ?. And regarding my 2nd comment didn't the and here do the job of where in my second subquery ?

Comment: As you've seen, no - it doesn't allow you to do that. As of the 2nd comment: run query I posted, compare it to your 1st query (which works). Then modify my query and instead of AND put WHERE, i.e. `select * from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno WHERE e.job = 'SALESMAN';` and you'll see what happens (query will work, but will also return wrong result).

Comment: i see, so when we you used and the job='SALESMAN' was still part of the join while if we use where instead it will be cut off and won't be considered as part of it and therfore the final result of the join will have the where condition appplied to it.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thanks alot for your help truly appreciated man